# redirect to POST method in same controller

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, redirect

I have a spring RestController and want to redirect to POST method in same controller with RequestBody.
any solution welcomes, not only redirect.

MyController:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addCompany", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addCompany(@Valid Company company, BindingResult result,
        HttpServletRequest request, Model model) throws Exception {
    //some logic
    //need to pass Company Object as RequestBody
    return "redirect:/app/postmethod/";
}

//Method to redirected
@RequestMapping(value = "/postmethod", method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
public String getData( @RequestBody(required=false) Company compnay, HttpServletRequest request, Model model) throws Exception {
    //some logic
    //required company object
    return "htmlpage";
}
```

I need to redirect my request to `/postmethod` from `addCompany` method in the same controller, I am open to use any feasible solution.

Comment: Why can't you just call getData?

Comment: Turo, can you give more details about it, how to use it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good explanation on this page [here](http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/www/post-redirect.html).

For protecting users against inadvertently (re)submitting a POST transaction which they had not intended, or submitting a POST into a context which they would not have wanted.

So you can set the data in session and using get method to call post method if you want to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Check here:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-redirect-and-forward#redirecting-an-http-post-request

> As per HTTP 1.1 protocol reference, status codes 301 (Moved
>   Permanently) and 302 (Found) allow the request method to be changed
>   from POST to GET. The specification also defines the corresponding 307
>   (Temporary Redirect) and 308 (Permanent Redirect) status codes that
>   don't allow the request method to be changed from POST to GET.

```
@PostMapping("/redirectPostToPost")
public ModelAndView redirectPostToPost(HttpServletRequest request) {
    request.setAttribute(
      View.RESPONSE_STATUS_ATTRIBUTE, HttpStatus.TEMPORARY_REDIRECT);
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/redirectedPostToPost");
}

@PostMapping("/redirectedPostToPost")
public ModelAndView redirectedPostToPost() {
    return new ModelAndView("redirection");
}
```

The request body will be passed. Here is an example using your code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("app")
public class TestController {

    @PostMapping("/addCompany")
    public ModelAndView addCompany(@RequestBody Company company, HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println("First method: " + company.name);
        request.setAttribute(
                View.RESPONSE_STATUS_ATTRIBUTE, HttpStatus.TEMPORARY_REDIRECT);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/app/postmethod/");
    }

    @PostMapping("/postmethod")
    public void getData(@RequestBody Company company) {
        System.out.println("Redirected: " + company.name);
    }

    public static class Company {
        String name;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

When using POST request to `http://localhost:8080/app/addCompany` with body `{"name": "Test Company"}`, in the output I receive next:

```
First method: Test Company
Redirected: Test Company
```

Comment: spring is awesome, but how to pass the data?

Comment: Correct  石荒人, How to pass data ? it just a simple call , I am already doing

Comment: @HiteshKumar you want to pass your additional custom data? Because all data from the request will already be passed

Comment: Yes, how I will pass the Company object ? I am testing with session.

Comment: @HiteshKumar in both methods? Could you share a code you use?

Comment: no, while redirecting, Thank you, it working with session variables